# How to attach a row header to a data frame in python. Row names should be taken from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      1            2         3
0.950389665 0.29695614  0.250323227
0.228821863 0.544082251 0.809445825
0.595764836 0.726256844 0.301979059
0.12775065  0.307534453 0.7791458
0.538780306 0.651055165 0.8450824
0.674011952 0.03239639  0.650357821
0.257926954 0.828308299 0.526425688
```

I want to attach the row names for the above dataframe by reading the a values of dictionary dictionary

dict:

```
 [dict_values(['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh'])]
```

This is the code i used:

```
Result_matrix = df.set_index([dictionary.values()])
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-79-dc4a38b0a2d5>", line 1, in <module>
    enrond_matrix = enrond_dataframe.set_index([ reverse_dictionary.values()])

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2830, in set_index
    level = frame[col]._values

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1971, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1645, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\30295\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2444, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 156, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5210)
```

Kindly help me with this.

If possible i want to have the end result as a numpy array (matrix form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert to `list` first:

```
Result_matrix = df.set_index([list(d.values())])
print (Result_matrix)
                1         2         3
First    0.950390  0.296956  0.250323
Second   0.228822  0.544082  0.809446
Third    0.595765  0.726257  0.301979
Fourth   0.127751  0.307534  0.779146
Fifth    0.538780  0.651055  0.845082
Sixth    0.674012  0.032396  0.650358
Seventh  0.257927  0.828308  0.526426
```

Or assign output:

```
df.index = d.values()
print (df)
                1         2         3
First    0.950390  0.296956  0.250323
Second   0.228822  0.544082  0.809446
Third    0.595765  0.726257  0.301979
Fourth   0.127751  0.307534  0.779146
Fifth    0.538780  0.651055  0.845082
Sixth    0.674012  0.032396  0.650358
Seventh  0.257927  0.828308  0.526426
```

Last for numpy array add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), but information about rows names is lost:

```
print (Result_matrix.values)
[[ 0.95038966  0.29695614  0.25032323]
 [ 0.22882186  0.54408225  0.80944582]
 [ 0.59576484  0.72625684  0.30197906]
 [ 0.12775065  0.30753445  0.7791458 ]
 [ 0.53878031  0.65105517  0.8450824 ]
 [ 0.67401195  0.03239639  0.65035782]
```

Comment: @jezreal - This has worked. Thanks a lot for your help